# Why does this exponential identity hold? $3\cdot 2^{2n+2} - 3\cdot2^{2n} = 3\cdot2^{2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, exponential-sum

Can someone explain how this is valid?

$$3\cdot 2^{2n+2} - 3\cdot2^{2n} = 3\cdot2^{2n}$$

Thanks so much!

Comment: It's not. However, the left-hand expression is equal to $9 \cdot 2^{2n}$.

Comment: Is it possible that first exponent should be $2n+1$?

Answer (score 2):

Taking out a common factor allows you to rewrite the expression as follows:
$$3\cdot2^{2n+2}-3\cdot2^{2n}=3\cdot2^{2n}\cdot(2^2-1)=3^2\cdot2^{2n}.$$
This shows that your formula is *not* valid; it's off by a factor $3$.

Comment: Get the power $2n$ on the second term and you'll have it.